# Is there a way to avoid autofocus on workspace on the file that opens when we close another? -- VisualStudio Code v1.46.0

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code

When I have several tabs open and I close one of them, the editor changes to the last one used. When that happens autofocus is also done on that file in the workspace panel. if possible I would like to disable that autofocus but I did not find the option in settings. Any help is welcome

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713391/how-to-disable-file-auto-focus-in-explorer-when-same-file-is-opened-in-tab can you check this?

Comment: thanks very much! the title of the question confused me. should i delete this one?

Comment: Nah, leave it! someone might think on the same lines as you and can find this!